# JPA - how check relations before commit?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Let say that I have complicated user management system. In this scenario User can be in relation with Group(s) and Groups can be in relation with Role(s). Additionally Groups can contains other Groups.

I have assumption that in "account management" case, current user can't lost role which allow do "account management" process. I wonder how will be the best way to implement that use case.

Lets try consider simple scenario:
E.g. in below hierarchy user is connected with our role by groups G3 and G5.

```
---USER---
|        |
G1       G3----
|        |    |
G2       G5   G6
         |
   REQUIRED_ROLE
```

During G3 group edition someone try change G3 group members e.g. to G7 (for simplification wihout roles)

```
---USER---
|        |
G1       G3----
|        |    |
G2       G7   G6
```

commit that change will remove "account management" role from user hiererchy and user will not be able to editing accounts.

My only idea is to read all groups and roles into memory and try change manually all dependencies to check if role will be still assigned after commit. But that solution can be source of potential bugs in future and is not elegant.
Does anyone have idea how it can be solved in elegant way?

Comment: Is User the person editing the database or is that a different user?

Comment: User after log in "play with" the whole system and actions has impact on DB state.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a non-trivial use case you can't use regular integrity constraints.  You will have to do a pre-commit trigger to scan the hierarchy and determine the the user has the required permission.  If not, throw an exception.